# A replacement exclamation for "Gee" or "Man"?

Tags: synonyms, colloquialisms, interjections

Sometimes, I might say 'Man', as the precursor to a statement as in this recent example I said to myself after reading something: "Man, to  give anything a label will always technically be reductive, and thereby cause assumptions..." or "Man, there are a lot of people here."

I don't like using 'man' since it sounds too casual to me, and I've never used 'gee' since it sounds outdated. I sometimes use a 'Hmm,', but it sounds pretentious. "Eureka" eureka wouldn't quite fit the situation here.

To simply omit the exclamation changes the implication of the sentence, indicating it is a fact, rather than something that came from your thoughts.

Right now, my choice of interjection would be a brief "Hnn,".
Can anyone suggest a nice more 'scientific' alternative, maybe something you've seen on a show, read an intellectual say, or use yourself?

---

Side Note: Google's dictionary (oxford pocket) doesn't actually list 'gee' as a synonym for 'man', maybe this should be added.

Comment: When prefacing a "profound" statement you could use *certainly*, *indeed*, *gee*, *man*, *wow*, and a host of others. But none of these interjections has precisely the same feel as the others, and feel is important.

Comment: I suggest, "You know, to give anything a label will always technically be reductive, and thereby cause assumptions..."

Comment: You don't need to provide an interjection at all . . .

Comment: I am going to vote to close this question, as any answer would be opinion.. However, I use: (yes) well............, eh............, really............, so,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,. among others.

Comment: closing question?  jeesh!

Comment: Afez, just a note on your side note: *gee* is **not** a synonym for *man*. Just because two words belong to the same category - in this case, interjection or exclamation - it doesn't imply they mean the same thing. Hence, *shit* is not a synonym for *God* in the sentence "Shit [God], that hurts!"

Comment: If you think “gee” is outdated, then you probably won’t like ‘‘golly’’ either — but [“gosh” seems to be rising in popularity](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=gee%2Cgolly%2Cgosh&year_start=1800&year_end=2008).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps, the item being looked for was not an alternative interjection, but a form of more effective communication.

When stating something to another person, starting with their name is very effective.

- "Milva, there are a lot of people here today."

When stating something to yourself, or others, just using body language to indicate you are thinking, like a tilted head, or eyes cast slightly downwards, is less casual than 'man'.

- /Tilts head 5 degrees/ "There are a lot of people here today."